# Google sheets Google maps API, Reference Error: google not defined

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to map the distance between two columns of addresses in a google sheet using the functions below. I'm getting the "google not defined" error that apparently when used in a web page context, results from trying to access the google object before the page has fully loaded.

Why am I getting this error in google sheets? Am I not allowed to use the same API?

The error is thrown by the `getDrivingMiles` function.

```
var alert = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert
var active_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var directionsService;

function onOpen()
{
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  travel_mode = google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING;

  alert = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert
  active_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  options = [
  {
    name: "Calculate Mileage",
    functionName: "getDistanceInMiles"
  }, ];
  active_sheet.addMenu("Driving Distance", options);
}

function getColNumberByName(column_name)
{
  var whole_sheet_data = active_sheet
    .getRange("A1:1")
    .getValues();
  var col_number = whole_sheet_data[0].indexOf(column_name);
  return (col_number)
}

function getColDataByColname(column_name)
{
  var col_number = getColNumberByName(column_name);
  if (col_number != -1)
  {
    return active_sheet
    .getRange(2, col_number + 1, active_sheet.getMaxRows())
    .getValues();
  }
}

function getRangeByColname(column_name)
{
  var col_number = getColNumberByName(column_name);
  if (col_number != -1)
  {
    return active_sheet.getRange(2, col_number + 1, active_sheet.getMaxRows())
  }
}

function getDistanceInMiles()
{

  var origins = getColDataByColname('From Address');
  var destinations = getColDataByColname('To Address');
  var distance_col = getColNumberByName('Distance in Miles');
  var num_addresses = origins.length;
  var origin = "";
  var destination = "";
  var distance = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < num_addresses; i++)
  {
    origin = origins[i][0];
    destination = destinations[i][0];
    if (origins[i][0] == "")
    {
      break;
    }
    Logger.log(origin + " to " + destination);

    var request = {
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status)
    {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
      {
        Logger.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value); // the distance in metres
      }
      else
      {
        // oops, there's no route between these two locations
        // every time this happens, a kitten dies
        // so please, ensure your address is formatted properly
      }
    });
  }
}

function getDrivingMiles(origin, destination)
{
  Utilities.sleep(1000)
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .getDirections();

  if (directions && directions.error_message)
  {
    throw directions.error_message
  }

  if (directions && directions.routes && directions.routes[0] && directions.routes[0].legs && directions.routes[0].legs[0] && directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance) 
  {
    return directions
    .routes[0]
    .legs[0]
    .distance
    .value/1609.34;
  }

  return "";
}
```

Comment: "apparently when used in a web page context". Are you using this script in a "webpage context"?

Comment: No. In a google sheet.

Comment: I've loaded your code. `getDrivingMiles` works fine - no errors. It is not called by any script listed in your question and it is 100% valid Google Maps Service - I doubt that it is the source of the error. The other scripts are a mish-mash: `getDistanceInMiles` comes from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/levymetal/5083949), use the Maps API and requires `scripts.html` to call the Google Maps API. `onOpen`: I am such a poor coder that I can't make any sense of it at all. My suggestion: delete everything but `getDrivingMiles` and it will work fine.

Comment: @Tedinoz -- that would be my preferred method. However, my sheet has so many addresses, I was getting timeout errors despite putting in a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite Google Apps Script being a subset of Javascript and sharing many features, they are not to be programmed the same way. Namely, since there is no "google" object declared in the global scope of your application (or any GAS application by default) it is returning an error upon referencing it.

In order to access Maps APIs from your GAS application, you should use either [`URLFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) or, even better, **the supported built-in services**. In your case, that would be using the [Maps Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps).

You can see more information in the following links:

- [Class Maps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps). Supported calls to the service.
- [Class DirectionFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder). Using direction finder. Includes examples that can be very useful to you.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was copying code designed for a web page and trying to use it in an app script. Different interfaces.